# git log excluding 100+ commits

Tags: git

I have a list of 100+ commit IDs.
I'd like to `git log` my whole repo but I need to exclude these mentioned commits.

I know, there is `git log --grep=something` but I can't imagine how this command would look like with 100+ elements. Is there a simpler way to achieve it?

Comment: Is there anything to these commits? E.g. are they all one after another? Or are they just random commits from the repository? And why do you need them excluded anyway?

Comment: They're cherry picked into another branch. But ill try to use `git log --cherry-pick` command or `git-cherry`. The problem is im not sure, that all this commits was cherry picked. But im sure about my change log where are this commits listed.

Comment: @Kasyx But you still want a default log format? I think you should override the pager: GIT_PAGER='foo | less' git log. foo is the command to drop the commits in the list. It can be a sed or awk program.

Comment: @basin I have much more extended command (`git log --pretty="%H [%ad] - %s" --since="2012-12-19" --no-merges --date=short`) but i shown only an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` has the right options for you. From the man page of grep:

> `-f FILE, --file=FILE`
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)
>
> `-v, --invert-match`
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)

So you can simply do:

```
git log --pretty=oneline | grep -v -f list_to_exclude
```

Comment: Didn't know about the -f flag

Comment: @basin, me neither. I just searched for the OP's question, came across the solution on the internet, cross-checked with the man-page and wrote it here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have log format format:

```
--pretty="%H [%ad] - %s"
```

and the list of commits in the file exclude.lst, each commit on new line;
Then to exclude these commits, use:

```
# generate the sed program to exclude
while read c; do
    echo "/^$c /D"
done > /tmp/exclude.sed < exclude.lst

# filter out
git log --pretty="%H [%ad] - %s" | sed -f /tmp/exclude.sed
```